# How to solve a simple first-order BVP? When do solutions exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem, periodic-functions

I would like to solve the following boundary value problem:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+ay(x)=f(x),$$
such that
$$y(0)=y(L),$$
i.e. $y(x)$ is periodic in $x$ with period $L$. Note that $a$ is a constant and $f(x)$ is a predetermined function which is also periodic with period $L$. For what values of $a$ does a solution exist and is the solution always unique?

Assume
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty y_n\exp(ik_n x),$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n\exp(ik_n x),$$
where
$$k_n = 2\pi\frac{n}{L}.$$
Multiplying the ODE by $\exp(-ik_m x)$ and integrating from $0$ to $L$ gives,
$$(ik_m+a)y_m = f_m,$$
$$\implies y_m = \frac{f_m}{ik_m + a},$$
assuming $ik_m + a \ne 0$.
Can we conclude a unique solution exists iff $a\ne -ik_n \forall n$? What if $a=-ik_m$, what is the solution then? Is $y_m$ a free parameter?

Also, do you know how to calculate a solution using the integrating factor? Using an integrating factor gives
$$y(x)=\exp(-ax)\int\exp(ax)f(x)dx,$$
what should the limits in the integral be to ensure the BCs are satisfied?

Comment: You can write this diff eq as $\frac{d}{dx}\Big[ye^{ax}\Big]=e^{ax}f(x)$

Comment: What should you use as limits in the integral to ensure the boundary conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Note $y(x)=e^{-ax}\int_{0}^xe^{a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau+y(0)e^{-ax}$ is a particular solution to your differential equation. Moreover, $$y(0)=y(L) \iff e^{aL}y(L)-y(0)=\int_0^Le^{a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau$$

Comment: Thanks. Should it be $$y(0)=y(L)\implies y(0)=e^{-aL}\int_0^L e^{a\tau} f(\tau) d\tau + y(0)e^{-aL},$$ $$\implies y(0)(e^{aL}-1)=\int_0^L e^{a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau?$$

Comment: Notice $$y(L)=e^{-aL}\int_0^Le^{a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau+e^{-aL}y(0)$$ Multiply both sides by $e^{aL}$ and subtract $y(0)$ to get $$e^{aL}y(L)-y(0)=\int_0^Le^{a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau$$